# Dojo Struts 2.0.12

Tags: struts2, dojo

In my struts 2.0.12 application I'm trying to use s:datetimepicker
but it does not render.

Firebug error: dojo is not defined
on dojo.require("dojo.widget.DatePicker");

My jsp page

```
 <%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
 .
 .
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
   <s:head theme="ajax" debug="true"/>
 .
 .
 </head>
 <body>
 .
 .
 <s:datetimepicker name="dataInizioRicerca" label="data inizio ricerca (yyyy-MM-dd)" displayFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"/>
 .
.
</body>
```

What's wrong? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

For use datetimepicker you need to use struts-dojo-tags, this came into de struts-dojo-plugin.jar of struts library, now u have the tags, loaded whit

and put inside head tag

to visualize the date time picker....

... maybe this can help you....

Answer (score 1):

Yes you missed the Ajax header (Ajax struts theme) tag.

This loads the Dojo Javascript files at the start of the page.

Put the following in your HTML head:

`<head>
[..other stuff]
<s:head/> <!-- Struts 2 Ajax/Dojo needed for calendar -->
</head>`

By the way - the above post talks about struts 2.1.x and not struts 2.0.12 (the one you are using)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a while since this thread was updated but if someone experiences the problem above and does a search they might end up here and the following observations may be useful.

I got similar issues when using Dojo with Struts 2.1 but that was down to the major changes in how struts 2 works with Dojo. A useful resource in sorting out those issues can be found here:
[Toubleshootng guide for migrating from Struts 2.0.x to Struts 2.1.x](http://cwiki.apache.org/S2WIKI/troubleshooting-guide-migrating-from-struts-20x-to-21x.html)

If getting Dojo working was still causing problems you could try using the Struts 2 jquery plugin, (do a search for that as I am not allowed to post 2 hyperlinks)

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop using struts dojo tags and use dojo independently. struts -dojo is not supported any more.